# MySQL Order by Results of SUM

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql SELECT as follows

```
SELECT SUM(s.cuts) as scuts, SUM(s.top) as swins, SUM(s.top_10) as stop_10,
```

and I would like to order the results by the sums:

```
ORDER BY ((swins*10)+(stop_10*4)+scuts) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Is this possible?

I have searched other posts, but can't find an answer.

Comment: Did you try it? *An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column:* (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: Ordering is done by the result of your select, not by some value you want to calculate in ORDER BY.

Comment: @MykolaEvpak: Of course you can order by a calculation.

Comment: @juergen d You say if you did select "height" from table you can do  order by "width"? ) I suppose you didn't understand what I said. Sure you can order by sum(column) but you cannot do calculations in ORDER BY statement

Comment: @MykolaEvpak: Sure, if it makes sense to you. There is nothing that prevents that. But in this case here ordering by a calculation of something you select seems totally reasonable.

Comment: Why don't you want to do your calculation in SELECT statement, and than order by number of that column?

Comment: oh yes, I have tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: thanks for the link in the first comment. I can do what I want with the HAVING clause. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a SELECT alias in a SORT BY expression that is other than a bare name. (It's just an SQL restriction, related to name scoping, although more unambiguous cases could be allowed.)

But you can put a SELECT & SORT BY around the code you gave. Or for certain expressions you can use HAVING as suggested in comments.